# Left join from 2 tables with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tabl1e1 and table2 with data

table1

```
location    costA
 a           5
 a           10
 a           15
 b           11
 b           12
```

table2

```
Location    CostB
 a          100
 b          100
```

My goal to get the result

```
location    costA   costB
  a          5       100
  a          10       
  a          15       
  b          11      50
  b          12
```

My query

```
select T1.location, T1.cost
from (
  select location, cost
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by cost) rownumber
  from table1
) T1 left join (
  select location, cost
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by cost ) rownumber
  from table2
) T2 on T2.location = T2.cost and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
```

I got

```
location    costA    missing costB column
 a           5
 a           10
 a           15
 b           11
 b           12
```

Not sure why but can you point out the missing one. Thank you.

Comment: Is your goal result accurate? How can ```a``` have value of ```100``` and ```0``` in column ```costB```

Comment: sorry, there are no 0

Comment: so you want to apply from table B to the lowest cost from A always lowest?  (Since order isn't guaranteed in a table?)

Comment: ok with it as long as cost b fall in the same location for each group

Comment: select T1.location, T1.cost, t2.cost
from (
  select location, cost
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by cost) rownumber
  from table1
  ) T1 

left join (
  select location, cost
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by cost ) rownumber
  from table2
   ) T2 on T1.location = T2.location and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber

Comment: How do I give you credit ( check on anwser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are expecting three columuns in result and your select statement contains only 2.

```
select T1.Location, T1.Cost
```

2nd the join should be

```
T2 on T1.[location] = T2.[location] and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
```

Below is the complete working example

```
DECLARE @table1 as table
(
    [location] char,
    costA int
)
DECLARE @table2 as table
(
    [location] char,
    costB int
)

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES
 ('a', 5)
,('a', 10)
,('a', 15)
,('b', 11)
,('b', 12)
 
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES
 ('a', 100)
,('b', 100)

select T1.[location], T1.costA, T2.costB
from (
  select [location], costA 
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by costA) rownumber
  from @table1
) T1 left join (
  select [location], costB
  , row_number() over ( partition by location order by costB ) rownumber
  from @table2
) T2 on T1.[location] = T2.[location] and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
```

Answer (score 0):

The join

```
T2 on T2.location = T2.cost and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
```

should be on

```
 T2 on T1.location = T2.location and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
```

> ```
> select 
>   T1.location, 
>   T1.costA,
>   T2.costB
> from (
>   select 
>     location, 
>     costA,
>     row_number() over ( partition by location order by costA) rownumber
>   from table1
> ) T1 
> left join (
>   select 
>     location, 
>     costB, 
>     row_number() over ( partition by location order by costB ) rownumber
>   from table2
> ) T2 
> on T1.location = T2.location and T1.rownumber = T2.rownumber
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> location | costA | costB
> :------- | ----: | ----:
> a        |     5 |   100
> a        |    10 |  null
> a        |    15 |  null
> b        |    11 |   100
> b        |    12 |  null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=160e8f6153bb055fb01f5ed307b2db9b)*

Comment: Same result before and no column costB